# Add label outside bar

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have added label to the bar (which appears inside the bar) using the below code. Now if the width of the bar is less than the width of the label text, I want to show the label outside (right of the bar).

[Bar with label inside](http://uploadpie.com/1gZxr)

```
BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
CategoryItemLabelGenerator generator
            = new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator("{1}",
                NumberFormat.getInstance());
renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(generator);
renderer.setBaseItemLabelFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 7));
renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
renderer.setBasePositiveItemLabelPosition(new ItemLabelPosition(
            ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE3, TextAnchor.CENTER_RIGHT, TextAnchor.CENTER,
            0.0));
```

I tried using `setPositiveItemLabelPositionFallback`  method but it didn't help.

```
ItemLabelPosition p2 = new ItemLabelPosition(
            ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE3, TextAnchor.CENTER_LEFT,
            TextAnchor.CENTER_LEFT, 0.0);
renderer.setPositiveItemLabelPositionFallback(p2);
```

[bar with label cut](http://uploadpie.com/hwKUG)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code to

```
renderer.setBasePositiveItemLabelPosition(new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.INSIDE3, TextAnchor.CENTER_RIGHT, TextAnchor.CENTER, 0.0));
```

So the whole code is

```
BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
CategoryItemLabelGenerator generator = new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator("{1}", NumberFormat.getInstance());
renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(generator);
renderer.setBaseItemLabelFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 7));
renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
renderer.setBasePositiveItemLabelPosition(new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.INSIDE3, TextAnchor.CENTER_RIGHT, TextAnchor.CENTER, 0.0));

ItemLabelPosition p2 = new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE3, TextAnchor.CENTER_LEFT, TextAnchor.CENTER_LEFT, 0.0);
renderer.setPositiveItemLabelPositionFallback(p2);
```

Comment: @trashgod What is actually confusing me is even though I have set `ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE3` for setBasePositiveItemLabelPosition ,  the label appears inside the bar.

Comment: [`BarChartDemo5`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html) looks like a working example.